# Force close messages; no access to phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, force-close

Have only had my new Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i one week and while playing "Flow Free" game downloaded from Play Store my phone suddenly switched off and from then on constant "Force Close" messages appeared. I have no access to my phone. How can I get my phone back?

Answer (score 1):

### Safe Mode

You could try to boot your Ace into "safe mode", as described e.g. in the article [SAFE MODE On Samsung GALAXY ACE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1090072):

1. Switch off the phone by pressing on the Power button.
2. Turn the phone back on, while it is turning on press and hold the Menu button.
3. Continue to hold the Menu button until you see the Home screen. On the home screen you see it say Safe Mode on the left hand corner.

Now that you are in Safe Mode you can go and remove any buggy apps that you don't want to keep. To exit safe mode after your cleanup:

1. Turn off the phone by pressing the Power button.
2. Pull out the battery. Wait for 30 seconds.
3. Put the battery back in.
4. Start up the device and see if the Safe Mode on the left hand corner has disappear. If it's not there then you have successfully started your phone in the standard mode.

### Factory Reset

If that does not work out, there's always the *factory reset*. But be aware that this removes all your data plus the apps you installed yourself!

How to perform a *factory reset* on the Ace is e.g. described at [hard-reset.com](http://www.hard-reset.com/samsung-galaxy-ace-s5830-hard-reset.html):

Press and hold the <kbd>Home</kbd> plus <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons simultaneously, or try <kbd>Volume-Up</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> together.

Of course there's also a menu for this -- but as you wrote you have no longer access to your phone, above key combinations are the only things left working.